# Full-width Numbers convert to half-width Numbers in jQuery / JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

A would like to convert Full-width Numbers (e.g. １２３) to half-width Numbers (e.g. 123). I found code do this in PHP but not in JS. Could anyone helps? Thanks.

```
function fullWidthNumConvert(fullWidthNum){
    // Magic here....
    ....
    return halfWidthNum;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Do a string [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), using a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to match the characters in question. The [callback in `.replace()`'s second argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) can get the character code of the matched character and subtract from that to get the character code of the standard digit, then convert that back to a string.

```js
function fullWidthNumConvert(fullWidthNum){
    return fullWidthNum.replace(/[\uFF10-\uFF19]/g, function(m) {
      return String.fromCharCode(m.charCodeAt(0) - 0xfee0);
    });
}


console.log(fullWidthNumConvert("０１２３４５６７８９"));
console.log(fullWidthNumConvert("Or in the middle of other text: １２３. Thank you."));
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [String Normalize <sup>*MDN*</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize) with `"NFKC"` as the Unicode Normalization Form

```js
const str = "１５０７２１";
console.log(str.normalize('NFKC')); // 150721
```

https://www.unicode.org/charts/normalization/chart_Number-Decimal.html